# Applying rules in Agda

Tags: agda

I am new to Agda, and I think I still have a problem to think in that paradigm. Here is my question.. 
I have a type monoid and a type Group implemented as follows:

```
record Monoid : Set₁ where 
   constructor monoid
   field Carrier : Set
         _⊙_     : Carrier → Carrier → Carrier
         e       : Carrier
         leftId  : ∀ {x : Carrier} → (e ⊙ x) ≡ x 
         rightId : ∀ {x : Carrier} → (x ⊙ e) ≡ x
         assoc   : ∀ {x y z : Carrier} → (x ⊙ (y ⊙ z)) ≡ ((x ⊙ y) ⊙ z)

record Group : Set₁ where 
    constructor group 
    field m        : Monoid 
          inv      : Carrier → Carrier 
          inverse1 : {x y : Carrier} → x ⊙ (inv x) ≡ e
          inverse2 : {x y : Carrier} → (inv x) ⊙ x ≡ e
```

Now, I want to proof the following lemma :

```
 lemma1 : (x y : Carrier) → (inv x) ⊙ (x ⊙ y) ≡ y 
 lemma1 x y = ?
```

If I do it on paper, I will apply associativity then left identity.. but I do not know how to tell agda to apply these rules.. I have the problem of translating my thoughts to the Agda paradigm..

Any help is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do the proof on the paper, applying associativity and *then* left identity uses ony key property of the identity relation - transitivity. That is, when you have a proof of `p : x ≡ y` and `q : y ≡ z` you can combine them into a single proof of `trans p q : x ≡ z`. The `trans` function is already part of the standard library (`Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality` module), but its implementation is fairly simple anyways:

```
trans : {A : Set} {i j k : A} → i ≡ j → j ≡ k → i ≡ k
trans refl eq = eq
```

I'm using a bit different presentation of monoids and groups, but you can easily adapt the proof to your scenario.

```
open import Function
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

Op₁ : Set → Set
Op₁ A = A → A

Op₂ : Set → Set
Op₂ A = A → A → A

record IsMonoid {A : Set}
       (_∙_ : Op₂ A) (ε : A) : Set where
  field
    right-id : ∀ x → x ∙ ε ≡ x
    left-id  : ∀ x → ε ∙ x ≡ x
    assoc    : ∀ x y z → x ∙ (y ∙ z) ≡ (x ∙ y) ∙ z

record IsGroup {A : Set}
       (_∙_ : Op₂ A) (ε : A) (_⁻¹ : Op₁ A) : Set where
  field
    monoid    : IsMonoid _∙_ ε
    right-inv : ∀ x → x ∙ x ⁻¹ ≡ ε
    left-inv  : ∀ x → x ⁻¹ ∙ x ≡ ε

  open IsMonoid monoid public
```

(To keep things simple, indented code is written as part of the `IsGroup` record). We'd like to prove that:

```
  lemma : ∀ x y → x ⁻¹ ∙ (x ∙ y) ≡ y
  lemma x y = ?
```

The first step is to use associativity, that is `assoc (x ⁻¹) x y`, this leaves us with a goal `(x ⁻¹ ∙ x) ∙ y ≡ y` - once we prove that, we can merge these two parts together using `trans`:

```
  lemma x y =
    trans (assoc (x ⁻¹) x y) ?
```

Now, we need to apply the right inverse property, but the types don't seem to fit. We have `left-inv x : x ⁻¹ ∙ x ≡ ε` and we need to somehow deal with the extra `y`. This is when another property of the identity comes into play.

Ordinary functions preserve identity; if we have a function `f` and a proof `p : x ≡ y` we can apply `f` to both `x` and `y` and the proof should be still valid, that is `cong f p : f x ≡ f y`. Again, implementation is already in the standard library, but here it is anyways:

```
cong : {A : Set} {B : Set}
       (f : A → B) {x y} → x ≡ y → f x ≡ f y
cong f refl = refl
```

What function should we apply? Good candidate seems to be `λ z → z ∙ y`, which adds the missing `y` part. So, we have:

```
cong (λ z → z ∙ y) (left-inv x) : (x ⁻¹ ∙ x) ∙ y ≡ ε ∙ y
```

Again, we just need to prove that `ε ∙ y ≡ y` and we can then piece those together using `trans`. But this last property is easy, it's just `left-id y`. Putting it all together, we get:

```
  lemma : ∀ x y → x ⁻¹ ∙ (x ∙ y) ≡ y
  lemma x y =
    trans (assoc (x ⁻¹) x y) $
    trans (cong (λ z → z ∙ y) (left-inv x)) $
          (left-id y)
```

---

Standard library also gives us some nice syntactic sugar for this:

```
  open ≡-Reasoning

  lemma′ : ∀ x y → x ⁻¹ ∙ (x ∙ y) ≡ y
  lemma′ x y = begin
     x ⁻¹ ∙ (x ∙ y)  ≡⟨ assoc (x ⁻¹) x y ⟩
    (x ⁻¹ ∙ x) ∙ y   ≡⟨ cong (λ z → z ∙ y) (left-inv x) ⟩
     ε ∙ y           ≡⟨ left-id y ⟩
     y               ∎
```

Behind the scenes, `≡⟨ ⟩` uses precisely `trans` to merge those proofs. The types are optional (the proofs themselves carry enough information about them), but they are here for readability.

---

To get your original `Group` record, we can do something like:

```
record Group : Set₁ where
  field
    Carrier : Set
    _∙_     : Op₂ Carrier
    ε       :     Carrier
    _⁻¹     : Op₁ Carrier

    isGroup : IsGroup _∙_ ε _⁻¹

  open IsGroup isGroup public
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.. I appreciate your effort

Comment: One more point, what is the $ that you have added to the 'lemma' function?

Comment: @ymmagdi: Just an operator that helps to reduce the number of parens, `f $ x` is just `f x`, so you can write `f $ g x` instead of `f (g x)`.